# Show that given a neighborhood $U \supseteq p^{-1} (y)$ in $X$ there exists a neighborhood $V_y \ni y$ in $Y$ such that $p^{-1} (V_y) \subseteq U.$

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a covering map of finite degree with $Y$ compact. Then given $y \in Y$ and given an open neighborhood $U \supseteq p^{-1} (y)$ in $X$ there exists an open neighborhood $V_y \ni y$ in $Y$ such that $p^{-1} (V_y) \subseteq U.$

Could anyone give me some suggestion as to how to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any covering map of finite degree $n$, we do not need the assumption that $Y$ is compact.

Let $W_y$ be an evenly covered open neighborhood of $y$. Then $p^{-1}(W_y) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{y,i}$ with open $U_{y,i} \subset X$ such that the restrictions $p_{y,i} : U_{y,i} \xrightarrow{p} W_y$ are homeomorphisms. Note that for each $M \subset W_y$ we have $$p^{-1}(M) = p^{-1}(M) \cap p^{-1}(U) =  p^{-1}(M) \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{y,i}\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n(p^{-1}(M) \cap U_{y,i}) \\
= \bigcup_{i=1}^n p_{y,i}^{-1}(M) .$$

Given an open neighborhood $U$ of $p^{-1}(y)$, let $V_{y,i} = p(U \cap U_{y,i}) = p_{y,i}(U \cap U_{y,i})$. The $V_{y,i}$ are open subsets of $Y$. Define
$$V_y = \bigcap_{i=1}^n V_{y,i} .$$
This is an open subset of $Y$ contained in $W_y$. We have
$$p^{-1}(V_y) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n p_{y,i}^{-1}(V_y) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n p_{y,i}^{-1}(V_{y,i}) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (U \cap U_{y,i}) \subset U. $$

Comment: I did the same thing some time ago but I got stuck at the stage as to how $p^{-1} (V_y) \subseteq U,$ as I can't conclude that $p^{-1} (p(U)) = U.$

Comment: Since $$V_{y,i} = p \left (U \cap U_{y,i} \right ) \subseteq p \left (U_{y,i} \right ) = W_y$$ it  follows that $$p^{-1} \left (V_{y,i} \right ) \subseteq p^{-1} \left (W_y \right ) = \bigsqcup\limits_{i = 1}^{n} U_{y,i}$$ and since $p\ \big \rvert_{U_{y,j}}\ \colon\ U_{y,j} \longrightarrow W_y$ is a homeomorphism for all $j = 1, \cdots, n$ it follows that $$p^{-1} \left (V_{y,i} \right ) = \bigsqcup\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left ( p\ \big \rvert_{U_{y,j}} \right )^{-1} \left (V_{y,i} \right ).$$

Comment: ...and, we only know that $\left ( p\ \big \rvert_{U_{y,i}} \right )^{-1} \left (V_{y,i} \right ) = U \cap U_{y,i},$ for all $i = 1, \cdots, n.$

Comment: Got it. The idea is to use similar trick as in the last two comments but in a modified form. We have $$\begin{align*} p^{-1} \left (V_y \right ) & = \bigsqcup\limits_{j = 1}^{n} \left ( p\ \big \rvert_{U_{y,j}} \right )^{-1} \left (\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n} V_{y,i} \right ) \\ & \subseteq \bigsqcup\limits_{j = 1}^{n} \left ( p\ \big \rvert_{U_{y,j}} \right )^{-1} \left (V_{y,j} \right ) \\ & = \bigsqcup\limits_{j = 1}^{n} \left (U \cap U_{y,j} \right ) \\ & = U \cap \left (\bigsqcup\limits_{j = 1}^{n} U_{y,j} \right ) \\ & = U \cap p^{-1} \left (W_y \right ) \\ & \subseteq U \end{align*}$$

Comment: This might not relevant to this question but I hope you give me some idea and hence I can't refrain myself from asking this question $:$ Can $[0,1]$ be locally homeomorphic to $S^1\ $? I think it's not because any local neighbourhood of $S^1$ is homeomorphic to the unit interval $(0,1)$ as $S^1$ is an $1$-manifold but any local neighbourhood of $0$ (resp. $1$) in $[0,1]$ looks like $(0,a]$ (resp. $(b,1]$) for some $a \in \mathbb R$ (resp. for some $b \in \mathbb R$) which are not homeomorphic to $(0,1).$ But how do I prove it using the definition of local homeomorphism? Any help?

Comment: Sorry I meant any local neighborhood around $0$ in $[0,1]$ is of the form $[0,a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa The local homeomorphism question should not be discussed on comments. You should ask a new question.

Comment: What I think is the following $:$ I know that any local homeomorphism is continuous and open. From here I think it is easy to show that composition of finitely many local homeomorphisms is also a local homeomorphism. Therefore in order to show that $[0,1]$ and $S^1$ are not locally homeomorphic it is enough to show that $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ are not locally homeomorphic. Now if $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ were locally homeomorphic there exists $a \gt 0$ such that $[0,a)$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R.$ Since $[0,a)$ is connected so $U$ must be an open interval...contd

Comment: But there exists no open interval which is homeomorphic to $[0,a)$ as removing $0$ from $[0,a)$ still yields a connected set but no matter what point we remove from an open interval it becomes disconnected. This should wrap things up!

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Your arguments are correct. But nevertheless I suggest not to use comments to give proofs.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa I made an update to incorporate your comments.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780341/1205961?