# How to prove that $a \ast b \not\sim b \ast a$ as based loops at $(0,0,0)$ in $X\ $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

> Consider the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ given by $\widetilde X : = (S^1 + (1,0,0)) \times \mathbb Z \cup \{(0,0,z)\ |\ z \in \mathbb R \}$
>
> and the subspace of of $\mathbb R^2$ $$X : = (S^1 + (1,0,0)) \cup (S^1 + (-1,0,0)).$$
>
> Define a covering map $\pi : \widetilde X \longrightarrow X$ which projects down $(S^1 + (1,0,0)) \times \mathbb Z$ onto the circle $(S^1 + (1,0,0))$ and wrap the line $\{(0,0,z)\ |\ z \in \mathbb R\}$ on the other circle i.e. $S^1 + (-1,0,0).$ Consider the loop $a, b$ in $X$ defined by $a(t) = (\cos (2 \pi t) - 1, \sin (2 \pi t),0)$ and $b(t) = (1 - \cos (2 \pi t), -\sin (2 \pi t), 0)$ in $X.$ Then show that $a \ast b \not\sim b \ast a$ as based loops at $(0,0,0)$ in $X$ by showing that their lifts are not based homotopic as paths in $X.$

By the virtue of the homotopy lifting lemma it follows that if such a homotopy exists in $X$ then the unique lifts of $a \ast b$ and $b \ast a$ starting at $(0,0,0)$ in $\widetilde X$ should be fixed endpoint homotopic in $\widetilde X.$ Also I notice that $\widetilde X$ retracts to $S^1 + (1,0,0)$ just by projecting everything down to $(S^1 + (1,0,0)) \times \{0\}.$ Hence $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \pi_1 (\widetilde X)$ and consequently $\widetilde X$ has a non-trivial fundamental group. Will that help anyway?

Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $\widetilde{X}$. For $(S^1+(1,0,0))\times\Bbb Z$ to make sense as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$, I would assume you wish for $S^1+(1,0,0)$ to be a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. But $(1,0,0)$ isn't an element of $\Bbb R^3$ - did you just mean $(1,0)$? I have the same objection for $X$ and in the definition of $a,b$; there seems to be a redundant third coordinate

Comment: @F.Shrike$:$ Indeed $S^1 + (1,0,0)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ It is in fact the copy of $S^1$ lying on the $xy$-plane centered at $(1,0,0)$ and by $(S^1 + (1,0,0)) \times \mathbb Z$ I think that we are taking a copy of $S^1$ on each plane parallel to the $xy$ plane which are integer distance away from each other. Thus the Cartesian product is indeed in $\mathbb R^3.$

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside my objections in the comments, I'm reasonably sure I know what you meant to say and I will proceed under that assumption. I leave some hints below to give you something to think about.

So, a basic first step is calculating these unique lifts of $ab$ and $ba$. Once you do this, you'll realise you should be thinking about the subspace: $$Y=(S^1\times\{0\}+(1,0,0))\cup((0,0)\times I)\cup(S^1\times\{1\}+(1,0,0))$$

You correctly noted $\widetilde{X}$ retracts onto each subcircle. You can think about this and observe $\widetilde{X}$ retracts onto $Y$. If $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ denote the lifts of $ab$ and $ba$ in $Y$ (well, in $\widetilde{X}$ but their images lie in $Y$) we only need to care about showing that $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1$ is not nullhomotopic in $Y$ (why?).

This is maybe silly but... $Y$ itself has a nice, easy to work with covering space, $\widetilde{Y}$ (its universal covering space is quite complicated to visualise, don't go for that one!) which looks like a ladder with evenly spaced rungs at the integers. You can compute the unique lift $\gamma$ in $\widetilde{Y}$ of $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1$. $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1$ is nullhomotopic in $Y$ if and only if $\gamma$ is (i) a loop and (ii) a contractible loop in $\widetilde{Y}$. It turns out $\gamma$ is a loop (when using the obvious covering map), but it should be quite clear that $\gamma$ is not nullhomotopic in $\widetilde{Y}$. Alternatively, you can choose the covering map $\widetilde{Y}\twoheadrightarrow Y$ to be such that $\gamma$ is not even a loop at all.

Comment: I know what are the liftings of $a \ast b$ and $b \ast a$ well in advance and your retraction seems fine to me. Essentially you are projecting everything below $z = 0$ to $z=0$ and projecting everything above $z = 1$ to $z = 1$ keeping the middle line segment fixed. Right?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa yes, that's right

Comment: Why do we only need to care about whether $\gamma_2^{-1} \gamma_1$ is nullhomotopic in $Y$ or not?

Comment: I don't even understand what $\widetilde Y$ is. Your proof is so sketchy.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa The fact $Y$ is a retract of $X$ and $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1$ is a loop contained in $Y$ implies the claim; the inclusion homomorphism $\iota_\ast:\pi_1(Y)\to\pi_1(\widetilde{X})$ (at a suitable basepoint) is injective and in particular has trivial kernel.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Well, like I said I just gave some hints, I didn't write up a full solution. This is partly because there wasn't much work in your question and partly because I feel like my solution can be followed after a little thinking. How can you nicely cover $S^1$? With $\Bbb R$ as we all know. How can you cover two copies of $S^1$? With two copies of $\Bbb R$! How can you cover $Y$? With two copies of $\Bbb R$ and the middle segment**s**! (question: why do we need multiple middle segments/"rungs" rather than just one?) That is what $\widetilde{Y}$ is.

Comment: Then each rung of the ladder maps homeomorphically onto the middle line segment. That is what you mean. Right?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Well, that's still true if I only use one rung. Think about the covering map criterion and what happens at the points in $Y$ where the middle segment intersects each circle - what is the preimage in $\widetilde{Y}$? It is for similar reasons to why $[0,1]$ is not a cover of $S^1$.

Comment: I think of the covering map in the following way $:$ Let us assume that the ladder is of unit width. Then as we proceed from $(0,0,n)$ to $(0,0,n + 1)$ it wraps the bottom circle in $Y$ once then when we take the rung joining $(0,0,n + 1)$ to $(1,0,n + 1)$ it maps homeomorphically onto the middle line segment and when we go from $(1,0,n + 1)$ to $(1, 0, n + 2)$ it then wraps the top circle. Can we take such a "zigzag" covering? It seems funny.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Formally, take $\widetilde{Y}=\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}\cup\Bbb Z\times I$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ and you can define the covering by mapping $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$ onto the two circles in $Y$ in the usual ways and by mapping $\Bbb Z\times I\twoheadrightarrow I$ as a projection and then including $I$ into the middle segment of $Y$.

Comment: The lift $\gamma$ starting at $(0,1)$ is the closed rectangular path joining $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$ followed by $(0,0)$ to $(-1,0)$ followed by $(-1,0)$ to $(-1,1)$ and finally followed by $(-1,1)$ to $(0,1)$ which is a loop based at $(0,1).$ Am I right?

Comment: Each such rectangle is homeomorphic to circle. May be using the same trick used to prove that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb Z$ it is now clear that the lift  $\gamma$ is the lift starting at $(0,1)$ which traverses along the rectangle once in the clockwise direction and hence it cannot be homotopic to the constant loop.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Yeah that’s right. More simply, once you’ve identified the loop $\gamma$, you notice $\widetilde{Y}$ retracts onto that rectangle so once again you can restrict attention to this rectangle which is homeomorphic to a circle; from this perspective $\gamma$ is clearly a generating loop of $\pi_1\cong\Bbb Z$ and in particular is not nullhomotopic in $\widetilde{Y}$.